How to Customize MUI Date Picker size for Mobile Screens?

I am using the DesktopDateTimePicker component from Material-UI (MUI) in my React application. This component is designed for desktop use, and it does not fit well on mobile screens.
I would like to customize the DesktopDateTimePicker to make it more mobile-friendly or use a different component that is better suited for mobile devices. Specifically, I need to adjust the size and layout of the picker UI so that it fits well on smaller screens.

Below is the solution for my issue.
  <DateTimePicker
    label="Select date and time"
    viewRenderers={{
      hours: renderMultiSectionDigitalClockTimeView,
      minutes: renderMultiSectionDigitalClockTimeView,
      seconds: renderMultiSectionDigitalClockTimeView,
    }}
  />


i would like to inform that this mui datepicker is pre-bulid responsive by mui.
that is i do in my project enter image description here
so you can check and install second time

Hi Yash, can you try with datetime picker? Because what can I see in your project is date only picker. Thanks !
